# didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is not called in another viewcontroller

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios8

I have two view controllers they are FirstPage and HomePage. Homepage is having tableview and add this view controller in FirstPage viewcontroller as follows

```
HomePage *objHomePage=[[HomePage alloc]init];
objHomePage.view.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 520.0, 375, 667);
[self.view addSubview:objHomePage.view];
```

but when call the didSelectRowAtIndexPath of tablew view in HomePage,it is not called.

Comment: are the tableView.delegate and tableView.datasource set? That's how you get the delegate callbacks you'll need. Also, this isn't a correct implementation of viewController containment... see answer

Answer (score 0):

I know this wasn't the question, but this is not a correct implementation of viewController containment... below is..

```
HomePage *viewController = [notification object];

[self addChildViewController:viewController];
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 520.0, 375, 667);
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
[viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I'd also check that inside HomePage, the it's tableView.delegate is set to self. That's the first thing I'd check with your issue.